# What he did was (to) reduce the cost. - with/without "to" - do they mean the same?

Tags: tense, cleft-constructions

**Example 1**
What he did was reduce the cost.

**Example 2**
What he did was to reduce the cost.

Does Example 1 mean "he reduced the cost"?
If yes, does Example 2 mean the same thing as Example 1?

I feel that Example 2 can mean "he did something and that something was to achieve the reducing of the cost."

Does Example 2 have two meanings?

Comment: Yes, #2 could mean "in order to".  Why he did what he did was to reduce the cost.